# Error when calling .setFocus on a form stored as a variable

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have an Access application with several subforms that contain different types of data all pulled from different sources. I have a button sitting at the top of the main form that will do different things depending on the currently-selected subform. I've been trying to refactor the Select statement called by this button so that there isn't so much repeated code.

Old code that works:

```
    Dim frm as Access.Form

    Select Case mainForm.tabLists.value
        Case List1.PageIndex
             set frm = subForm1.Form
             subForm1.setFocus
        Case List2.PageIndex
             set frm = subForm2.Form
             subForm2.setFocus
        Case List3.PageIndex
             set frm = subForm3.Form
             subForm3.setFocus
    End Select
```

New code that yields "RunTime error 2449, There is an invalid method in an expression":

```
    Dim frm as Access.Form

    Select Case mainForm.tabLists.value
        Case List1.PageIndex
             set frm = subForm1.Form
        Case List2.PageIndex
             set frm = subForm2.Form
        Case List3.PageIndex
             set frm = subForm3.Form
    End Select

    frm.setFocus
```

Debugging the runtime error points to

```
frm.setFocus
```

but I am unsure why it is not working. Setting "frm" as a watched variable and stepping through the code shows that is being properly assigned and in the older code "frm" is used in a couple other operations after the Select statement without fail.

Comment: You are setting the subform.focus in the 1st and subform.form.focus in the 2nd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
Dim sfrm As Subform

Select Case mainForm.tabLists.value
    Case List1.PageIndex
         Set sfrm = Me!subForm1
    Case List2.PageIndex
         Set sfrm = Me!subForm2
    Case List3.PageIndex
         Set sfrm = Me!subForm3
End Select

sfrm.SetFocus
```